# How to copy entire directory in Rails generator from templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

I am creating a rails generator and I want to copy an entire directory from templates.
I am using FileUtils.cp_r and it works but the matter is that i need to precise the path of template directory from the rails app directory instead of just having the relative path like using copy_file : 
For example, I have

```
FileUtils.cp_r 'lib/generators/cms/templates/content_wrappers', 'app/views/content_wrappers'
```

It works fine but I would like just to use a relative path like in copy_file if possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command to copy a whole directory in a generator method is simply:

```
def some_generator_method
  directory 'path_to_install_directory', 'path_to_source_directory'
end
```

Comment: According to Apidock this method has been deprecated. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Here are the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Actions:directory